# Qual a finalidade Message Queue MQ

Tags: redis, memcached

Já ouvi muito em falar de MessageQueue, e nunca utilizei na pratica. Mas antes disso, gostaria de saber qual é a necessidade e a sua finalidade de se usar um MQ. Pensando em escalabilidade e performance.

As vezes me confundo com armazenamento de cache, assim como o memcached e redis, onde posso usufluir Pub/SUb.

Comment: Redis e MemCache são sistemas mais usados para gerar Cache de Objetos e consultas a banco de dados o que não têm nada a ver com MessageQueue , que como o nome diz, é um gerenciador de Filas de Mensagens. São coisas muito diferentes. 
MQs são geralmente utilizados para processamento assíncrono mas que precisam obedecer uma certa ordem. Embora Redis suporte o paradigma Pub/Sub, quem precisa desse tipo de de tecnologia costuma usar JMS ou IBM MQ.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode encontrar várias explicações e definições semelhantes para sua pergunta, ao depender da plataforma utilizada.

Em resumo, permite que aplicativos independentes e potencialmente não concorrentes em um sistema distribuído se comuniquem uns com os outros.

Se você deseja realizar uma pesquisa mais aprofundada sobre o assunto, com detalhes mais técnicos e práticos sobre performance e desempenho, pode encontrar no link abaixo:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19909-01/817-3727/tuning.html

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Se quiser uma definição mais específica da resposta, pode especificar a plataforma de utilização para refinar as respostas.